# How to get a UIImage's image as an NSString?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uiimage

I need to get the value of a UIImage's image as a string.

Previously I was doing:

```
if(images[imageNo].image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"])
{
```

But now I have a lot more conditions so I would like to use a switch, doing:

```
switch(images[imageNo].image)
{
    case @"image1.png":
    break;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: This is not related to Xcode, retagged.

Comment: Sorry. I will try not to tag incorrectly again.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "the value of a UIImage's image as a string"?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question - why aren't you handling object identity in the 'Model' of your program (MVC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your approaches are incorrect. The first one relies on caching (which is not documented), meanwhile the second is a syntax error - the 'case' keywords expect a compile-time constant expression.

As far as I know, there's no such a method in the iOS SDK that would return an image's filename - simply because it's not a property of the image (what would it return for a programmatically created image?). You should instead try to operate on an NSDictionary, storing the UIImage objects associated with the filenames as keys, and comparing the keys using `isEqualToString:`.

So you should create your images only once, and store them in a dictionary:

```
// assuming `images` is an already created instance variable of your class
[images setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImgOne.png"] forKey:@"ImgOne.png"];
// and so on, with every image you need

// then once you have to check against a file name, use:
UIImage *img = [images objectForKey:@"FileName.png"];
if ([someImage isEqual:img]) {
    // you can now be sure that the image set to the object was once named "FileName"
}
```

Comment: Please can you expand on that a little bit. I am fairly new to XCode development and have never used an NSDictionary. Thanks!

Comment: @user1401690 sure, a moment. (Again, it's rather *iOS* development :) I do all my iOS programming without Xcode.)

Comment: Thanks, works great but is there any advantage to using this method with NSDictionary opposed to an NSArray? They appear very similar.

Comment: @user1401690 how would you store the keys in the array and still keep them associated to the images?

Comment: Oh sorry; I actually ended up using an NSArray instead of an NSDictionary. But your answer inspired me, I'll mark it as correct again since it's the closest answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mmm I am not sure what you want to accomplish here but using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]`, is definitely a very bad way to do the comparison as you are creating a new UIImage object on the fly for no reason at all, furthermore you are using the == operator when you should be using isEqual since they are objects.

I believe what you want to do is convert it to a base 64 string perhaps?. If so you an use this:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);

NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
```

Comment: Generating data representations on the fly is pretty expensive, too.

Comment: "you are creating a new UIImage object on the fly" - actually, no, OP has been lucky because that method uses caching. However, this undocumented behavior is still not to be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by `H2C03` is appropriate.  Use a dictionary to associate the names.

However, an alternative is using associative objects.  Note that there is a cost in both space and time using associative objects, but they are convenient for just this type of case (adding a category-property).

```
@interface UIImage (MyImageLabel)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *label;
@end


#import <objc/runtime.h>
@implementation UIImage (MyImageLabel)
static char const kImageLabelKey[1];
- (NSString*)label {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kImageLabelKey);
}
- (void)setLabel:(NSString *)label {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kImageLabelKey, label, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

Now, you can have a label property on your UIImage instances, like so:

```
myImage.label = someLabelStringCouldEvenBeFilename;
```

and

```
if ([myImage.label isEqualToString:someString]) {
}
```

The typical caveats apply regarding anything in a category.  Most will encourage you to use a unique prefix or postfix to differentiate your category methods from potential future Apple names.

Note, that you could add another method to the category, like this...

```
+ (UIImage)myImageNamed:(NSString*)name {
    id result = [self imageNamed:name];
    [result setLabel:name];
    return result;
}
```

and now you automatically set the label.

Of course, you could do this as a subclass, if you will always be creating your own image, and avoid the "nastiness" associated with associative objects (though all your images need to be MyUIImages).

```
@interface MyUIImage : UIImage
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *label;
@end

@implementation MyUIImage
// Now, you override imageNamed:
+ (UIImage*)imageNamed:(NSString*)name {
    UIImage *image = [super imageNamed:name];
    self.label = name;
    return image;
}
@end
```