# UIimagepickercontroller getting album name along with file name

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

```
How to get the selected image album name using UIimagepickercontroller?
```

Lets take an example for my requirement.

I have 3 albums in my phone (Saved Photos, Album 1, Album 2). Using UIimagepickercontroller I am selecting one image. How to know the selected image album name.

Using [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] I am able to get the selected image reference. But album name I am not able to get.

Please guide me how to proceed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341320/how-to-get-a-uiimages-image-as-an-nsstring

Comment: @Spynet - The links will help to get the file name not the album name. I need album name.

Comment: @karthika - The links will help to get the file name not the album name. I need album name.